# react-router-dom BrowserRouter not working after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is the first time I tried react. 
I create a project using `create-react-app`, then for routing, I use React Router V4 for web `react-router-dom`.

This is my `index.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

There's no problem when I start the server with `npm start`. But when I build the app with `npm run build`, putting it in my `www` folder in my Apache server and access it, I only get empty page with `<!-- react-empty: 1 -->` inside my `root div`.

```
<div id="root">
  <!-- react-empty: 1 -->
</div>
```

I have tried looking for similar cases, but the answer always about adding `historyApiFallback` in webpack.config.js or gulp, which I can't find anywhere in the `create-react-app` template.

I have tried `HashRouter`, it's working fine, but there's `/#/` in the url which is undesirable.

How can I get the BrowserRouter to work after I build the app?

Comment: Could you share the github repo? That's the only way to check your code. Never had this issue with create-react-app and react-router v4, so there must be something wrong on your side.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, this is my github repo. https://github.com/fadeltd/mall-app

Comment: the problem lies with how you serve the page. if you access it with something like `localhost/myproject`. then it will assume that the route needs to render will be the route with `myproject` path, so add prefix if this is the case

Answer (score 0):

Well, there was no problem at all. It worked, even if it was built using `npm run build`. My best guess is: you placed the files in the wrong folder.

When you build your code using `npm run build`, the `static` folder should be placed inside the `MallApp` folder. So your folder structure should be like this:

```
/var/www/mywebfolder/index.html
/var/www/mywebfolder/MallApp/static
```

Check your browser's console, I believe it contains errors. Failed to get the js and css files.

Comment: nope. everything loaded fine. console empty. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2anki8hncblooq6/AACySxivCMakTdH5-SW8KRQ3a

Comment: Only one possibility: your browser has HTML5 History API problem. Because it is needed by the BrowserRouter. As for your question regarding the webpack config, you need to run `npm run eject`. It will "extract" all the config files to your project folder. It is a one way operation though, so if you do not understand how to use babel, webpack, lint, etc.. don't do this.